# Google Analytics: define Goal as a series of event

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have a question relating to google analytics/javascript:

I am looking to define a series of events in a session as a goal. So that if somebody presse a button 4 times that is counted as a conversion so that I can use that for my analysis

Specifically, I have this website: thesispoint (dot) com where you see text in the middle and arrow buttons on the right and left. If somebody clicks on the right ("next") button 4 times I want to capture that as a conversion.

How would I do that smartly? Ideas and suggestions are super welcome!

Answer (score 0):

create a javascript variable and set it to 0.

create a javascript function and bind it to onclick of "next" button. this function should count how many times the button is clicked and send the event once 4th click is received.

```
<a id="nav-next" href="#" onclick="clickNext();">
<script>
var clickCount = 0
function clickNext() 
{
    clickCount++;
    if(clickCount == 4)
    ga(...) //code to add your event to google analytics
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you - that is super helpful!  

Would I need to include that in my html or in my custom javascript file?

And this would work for each "instance" (probably the wrong word) as in when the html is opened?

Comment: you can include this to your html. you don't need a js file if you don't have any yet. And this would work evey time the page is refreshed/opened

Comment: and I would just include it somewhere in the <body>?

Comment: javascript code is usually added to <header> section. but if you add it to <body> noone would complain :)